# Ruby and Rails "path not found" when installed using RVM on Docker

Tags: docker, rvm, dockerfile, codenvy

I'm working on a docker file to create a custom workspace on [Codenvy](https://codenvy.io). When I create the workspace everything seems to install correctly but when the workspace open and I enter `ruby -v` I get:

`bash: ruby: command not found`

Same for rails:

```
user@de98ec223612:/projects$ rails -v
bash: rails: command not found
```

If I type rvm list I get

```
user@de98ec223612:/projects$ rvm info

ruby-2.4.0:

  system:
    uname:        "Linux de98ec223612 3.10.0-514.10.2.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Mar 3 00:04:05 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux"
    name:         "Ubuntu"
    version:      "16.04"
    architecture: "x86_64"
    bash:         "/bin/bash => GNU bash, version 4.3.48(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)"
    zsh:          " => not installed"
    remote path:  "ubuntu/16.04/x86_64"

  rvm:
    version:      "rvm 1.29.1 (latest) by Michal Papis, Piotr Kuczynski, Wayne E. Seguin [https://rvm.io/]"
    updated:      "5 minutes 31 seconds ago"
    path:         "/home/user/.rvm"
    autolibs:     "[4] Allow RVM to use package manager if found, install missing dependencies, install package manager (only OS X)."

  ruby:
    interpreter:  "ruby"
    version:      "2.4.0p0"
    date:         "2016-12-24"
    platform:     "x86_64-linux"
    patchlevel:   "2016-12-24 revision 57164"
    full_version: "ruby 2.4.0p0 (2016-12-24 revision 57164) [x86_64-linux]"

  homes:
    gem:          "/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0"
    ruby:         "/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0"

binaries:
    ruby:         "/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/bin/ruby"
    irb:          "/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/bin/irb"
    gem:          "/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/bin/gem"
    rake:         "/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/bin/rake"

  environment:
    PATH:         "/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/bin:/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/bin:/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-open
jdk-amd64/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/bundle/bin:/usr/lib/postgresql/9.6/bin:/home/user/.rvm/bin"
    GEM_HOME:     "/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0"
    GEM_PATH:     "/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0:/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global"
    MY_RUBY_HOME: "/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0"
    IRBRC:        "/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/.irbrc"
    RUBYOPT:      ""
    gemset:       ""
```

which looks to me like things are installed correctly.

If I type `/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/bin/ruby -v` it shows the correct ruby version.  `/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/bin` is in the PATH why isn't it being searched?

Here is the relevant portion of my docker file if that helps.

```
# Install RVM
RUN gpg --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3 7D2BAF1CF37B13E2069D6956105BD0E739499BDB &&\
    echo progress-bar >> ~/.curlrc &&\
    \curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable &&\
    /bin/bash -l -c 'source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm'

# Install Ruby
RUN /bin/bash -l -c 'rvm requirements' &&\
    /bin/bash -l -c 'rvm install ${RUBY_VERSION}' &&\
    /bin/bash -l -c 'rvm use ${RUBY_VERSION} --default' &&\
    /bin/bash -l -c 'rvm rubygems current'

# Install bundler
RUN /bin/bash -l -c 'gem install bundler'

# Install Rails
RUN /bin/bash -l -c 'gem install rails'

RUN echo $PATH

EXPOSE 3000
WORKDIR /projects    

CMD /bin/bash -l -c 'source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm' && sudo service postgresql start && tail -f /dev/null
```

How can I get these commands to function without using `/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/bin`?

Answer (score 0):

If acceptable to your team it is probably easier to start with the base dockerfile that Eclipse Che provides for RoR: https://github.com/eclipse/che-dockerfiles/blob/master/recipes/ruby_rails/Dockerfile

That should get you the basics and it's kept up-to-date by the community. You can then extend this with any other tools, libraries, deps you need.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and eventually I fixed it by uploading a /root/.bashrc file ending with

```
source /opt/rvm/scripts/rvm
source /etc/profile.d/ruby.sh

export PATH=$PATH:/opt/rvm/bin
```

The lines with source, are added by me.  The export was added by RVM on install.  The rest of my bashrc file is the content that was installed by Debian.  I just added these lines.

My ruby.sh file contains

```
#!/bin/sh
export RUBY_HOME=/opt/rvm/rubies/default
```

For me, that does the trick.  When I login using /bin/bash (non-shell) or via /bin/bash -l -c "command goes here", my commands rvm and ruby both respond.  Also, my RUBY_HOME and GEM_PATH, ... are all filled.

My current ruby docker installation can be found here:
https://github.com/vindevoy/dockerhub-debian-ruby (sources)
https://hub.docker.com/r/vindevoy/debian-ruby/ (image)

Comment: Forgot to mention.  I install rvm in /opt.